# SetLocalTime causing PC to lag, how can I optimize it?

Tags: c++, performance, time

I want to create a program that will slow down Windows' time. I will be using `SetLocalTime()` for this. However, when I open the program, my PC starts to micro-stutter and game performances drops even though the process isn't using nearly any CPU.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Windows.h"
#include <thread> 
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

SYSTEMTIME st;
WORD hour;
WORD minute;
WORD second = 0;

int main()
{
    GetLocalTime(&st);
    hour = st.wHour;
    minute = st.wMinute;
    second = st.wSecond;

    for (;;)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
            st.wHour = hour;
            st.wMinute = minute;
            st.wSecond = second;
            SetLocalTime(&st);
        }
        second++;
        if (second == 60)
        {
            second = 0;
            minute++;
        }
        if (minute == 60)
        {
            minute = 0;
            hour++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you slow down time by changing Windows time, won't every program that use the system clock for their timing also start to slow down?

What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a program that will make windows time go slower as this will help me timescale an application that uses windows time

Comment: This may not be fixable, however my advice is to adjust the values and see if it increases or decreases the stutter.

Comment: @DorukGez "*this will help me timescale an application that uses windows time*" - then why not hook that specific application directly, instead of manipulating the OS itself?  Hook into `GetLocalTime()`, `GetSystemTime()`, and other related APIs and make them return whatever you want.

Comment: As far as I know, Cheat Engine does this and it doesnt work for this application. Maybe I am mistaken but how can I achieve this?

Comment: ***and it doesnt work for this application*** Maybe that means it won't work. Maybe the problem is the target application has code to handle the WM_TIMECHANGE message and this code causes the stutter since you are changing many times in a short period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the system clock, all the programs that use it for timing will also slow down.

From your comments, I could gather that you wish to time scale an application that uses time. So far, you didn't get more specific, so I cannot suggest anything more than a general approach.

Create a time manager class that, when you start your application, gets the current system time and store it as the base time of your application. Instead of using GetLocalTime() or GetSystemTime(), create a method in your class that will return the current time based on a time dilatation factor.

```
class TimeManager
{
  private:
    SYSTEMTIME _BaseTime;
    double _TimeDilatation;
  public:
    TimeManager();
    void SetTimeDilatation(double timeDilatation);
    void GetTime(LPSYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);
};

// Constructor will get the current local time.
TimeManager::TimeManager()
{
  GetLocalTime(&_BaseTime);
}

// Sets the time dilatation factor.
// 0.0 to 0.9 time will slow down
// 1.0 normal flow of time
// 1.1 to max double, time will go faster
void TimeManager::SetTimeDilatation(double timeDilatation)
{
  _TimeDilatation = timeDilatation;
}

// Get the current time taking into account time dilatation
void TimeManager::GetTime(LPSYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime)
{
  SYSTEMTIME resultingTime;
  SYSTEMTIME realTime;

  FILETIME ftime;
  ULARGE_INTEGER uliTime;
  __int64 lowerValue, higherValue, result;

  // Get the current local time
  GetLocalTime(&realTime);

  // Translate the base time into a large integer for subtraction
  SystemTimeToFileTime(&_BaseTime, &ftime);
  uliTime.LowPart = ftime.dwLowDateTime;
  uliTime.HighPart = ftime.dwHighDateTime;
  lowerValue = uliTime.QuadPart;

  // Translate the current time into a large integer for subtraction
  SystemTimeToFileTime(&realTime, &ftime);
  uliTime.LowPart = ftime.dwLowDateTime;
  uliTime.HighPart = ftime.dwHighDateTime;
  higherValue = uliTime.QuadPart;

  // Get the time difference and multiply the dilatation factor
  result = (higherValue - lowerValue) * _TimeDilatation;
  // Apply the difference to the base time value
  result = lowerValue + result;

  // Convert the new time back into a SYSTEMTIME value
  uliTime.QuadPart = result;
  ftime.dwLowDateTime = uliTime.LowPart;
  ftime.dwHighDateTime = uliTime.HighPart;
  FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftime,&resultingTime);

  // Assign it to the pointer passed in parameter, and feel like a Time Lord.
  *lpSystemTime = resultingTime;
}

int main()
{
  TimeManager TM;
  TM.SetTimeDilatation(0.75f); // the time will pass 75% slower

  for (;;)
  {
    SYSTEMTIME before, after;

    TM.GetTime(&before);
    
    // Do something that should take exactly one minute to process.

    TM.GetTime(&after);

    // Inspect the value of before and after, you'll see
    // that only 45 secondes has passed
  }
}
```

Note that it's a general idea to push you in the right direction. I haven't compile that code, so there maybe an error or five. Feel free to point them out, and I'll fix my post. I just didn't want to be too specific since your question is a bit broad ; this code may or may not help you depending on your use case. But that's generally how you slow down time without affecting system time.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer, I currently do get an error which is ```Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning C4717 'TimeManager::GetLocalTime': recursive on all control paths, function will cause runtime stack overflow``` Sadly, I am a beginner at programming and couldn't figure out how to fix it myself

Comment: Oh god, yes, sorry, I name the method the same as the API call. I thought that would help comprehension, but that's really not good. I'll edit.

Comment: Changing TimeManager::GetTime and to void TimeManager::GetTime and void TimeManager::SetTimeDilatation fixes declaration is incompatible